# Following CG Geek's Tornado tutorial, but hes using an older version of Blender

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, particles

[image: examples of whats going down]

I've been watching CG Geek (on youtube)'s tutorial on how to make a tornado in blender, and so far (even tho this is the first time i've really used blender) the project is going well, however, there was a section of the tutorial where CG Geek checked a box for render view that allows for a high resolution preview, and I could not follow those steps due to he is using an older version of blender than I am (i'm using blender 2.91).

so now I cant tweak the tornado because I can't see the high res view to tweak the lighting and colors due to I cannot see through the giant white minecraft blocks!  XD

Im not sure what I did wrong, but maybe someone out there can explain, for all I know, its a simple fix and im just dumb? lol

Comment: 2.90 Fluid simulation is not the same as the one in 2.80, you could download 2.80 from Blender website to follow the tutorial

Comment: Thank you, i will try that, hopefully i dont run into anymore troubles, but this seems like a great idea!